# "Account Buttons" or "Accounts Buttons"

Tags: word-choice

Is it correct to say "Account Buttons" or "Accounts Buttons" when referring to buttons, where every button represents different account?

If I use "Account Buttons" doesn't mean that there are few buttons for the same account?

Comment: Context is the key here...would multiple buttons for the same account be meaningful to whomever is using the buttons?  I'm guessing not and that they'd know that "account buttons" would mean buttons for the accounts.  "Accounts buttons" sounds very awkward to me.

Comment: Please provide an example sentence or two for context.

Comment: The buttons on a calculator (apart from the on/off button) are called the 'number buttons' and the 'function buttons'. The number buttons all input different numbers and the function buttons (+,-,=,√, etc) all do different things with the numbers so calling your buttons 'account buttons' is just like the calculator buttons.

Comment: I think context is king here. One might select among accounts and the other allow operations to be performed on the accounts and loosely similar queries have been troublesome pretty-much for ever. 

They're not exactly interchangeable but don't Questions like https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=attorneys+general or https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239729/why-does-pluralization-of-compound-words-typically-occur-in-the-middle-as-oppose overlap strongly?