# How to pluralise a proper noun that ends with an adjective

Tags: irregular-plurals

The phrase was "How many *Ark Royals* have there been in The Royal Navy".

[There have been 5 ships of the name *Ark Royal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Ark_Royal)

My question however is. is "*Ark Royals*" the correct plural form?

Should it instead be "How many *Arks Royal* have there been in The Royal Navy?"
or is that all moot and I should be asking "How many *HMSs Ark Royal* have there been in The Royal Navy?"

Comment: We italicize ship names. But we wouldn't include the plural *s* in the italicization: *Ark Royal*s

Comment: Even crème brûlées has been standardised in English. (I believe it's an option in French also, along with crèmes brûlées.) There's a corresponding thread addressing 'to He who must not be Named' (not 'Him'): it's usually best to see such multiword proper nouns as single lexemes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Ark Royal* is a name. Similar questions would be "How many Jasens are there in the world?" "How many Alexei Briggses are there?"

Ark Royal is not a title or an office like Postmaster General or Attorney General. Where a title like that has a postpositive adjective, then yes, pluralise the main noun: *Postmasters General, Attorneys General*. Even there, "Attorney Generals" is attested — eg [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/attorney-general).

But for a name, just pluralise. If it sounds awkward, you can always reword it, although I would suggest that *HMSs* is just as bad. "How many ships called *HMS Ark Royal* have there been in the Royal Navy?"

Comment: There's [an older question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239729/why-does-pluralization-of-compound-words-typically-occur-in-the-middle-as-oppose) about attorneys general or attorney generals. There's definitely a tendency to put the S at the end of many multi-word nouns but e.g. the Guardian still requires [attorneys general](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a).

Comment: I prefer "How many Royal Navy ships have been named *Ark Royal*?"